# Is there a way to pass React state into WebSocket.onmessage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, state, pass-by-reference

In TypeScript I am trying to read the value of a stateful variable (created with React.useState) from within a WebSocket's onmessage function. The value is only ever read as what it was at the time of onmessage definition (the initial state, *{state: 1}*).

*Foo* is created like a React component (*<Foo />*). *Bar* is called only once, but the state (*myState*) can be updated many times. Why isn't WebSocket.onmessage() using the reference passed to it?

I tried changing the type of propState from MyStatefulObject to &MyStatefulObject and executing the Bar function code directly, but it didn't work and Bar is actually quite large, so that is not ideal.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface MyStatefulObject {state: number}
interface BarProps {propState: &MyStatefulObject}

const Foo = () => {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState<MyStatefulObject>({state: 1}),
      [wsInitialized, setWSInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!wsInitialized) {
            Bar({propState: myState});
            setWSInitialized(true);
        }
    })

    return (
        <TextField 
            onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setMyState({state: +(e.target.value)});
                console.log(myState);                        // prints user input, confirming state change
            }}
        />
    )
}

const Bar = (p: BarProps) => {
    const ws = WebSocket('url');
    
    ws.onopen = () => {
        ws.send(/* Initialization Message */);
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e: MessageEvent) => {
        console.log(p.propState.state);                     // always prints 1
    };
}
```